# Rails wiki gem for production with devise/cancan - not personal use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, wiki, cancan, gollum-wiki

I've been looking into wikis for use in production in an existing rails app, not for personal use - have seen a few questions on wiki gems here but little outside of personal use.  Gollum seems simple to get up an running locally, but is it a good choice for production where you may have multiples users/groups that each have their own, secure wikis?

Besides Gollum, I have also looked into [Instiki](http://www.instiki.org/show/HomePage), [zena](http://zenadmin.org/en/documentation/Wiki/page735.html) and [Wagn](http://wagn.org/).

Some of the production requirements to consider:

1. Needs to play nice with existing models and storage - rails app is already using S3 to store media (videos, images) - those same
   assets will be combined with the wiki.
2. Need to be able to create separate wikis for groups within my company - seems like integration with devise/cancan is not too difficult.  Is it easy to add a separate repository for users/groups?
3. This is a general purpose wiki for internal use - non-technical employees from HR, finance, marketing, etc. will also be using it with different levels of access.  As such, would hope to swap out the text editor to something more user friendly such as [this wysihtml5 text editor](http://jhollingworth.github.com/bootstrap-wysihtml5/).

Is there anything I should be concerned about flexibility-wise with Gollum before investing too much time in it?  Any advice is much appreciated and hopefully this helps others!

Comment: Just incase anyone decides to respond, I installed Gollum, which was as easy as advertised.  Problems for me are that you can't customize the html/css and I don't think I have a way to embed wiki functionality into existing pages and other controllers.  Will probably try Instiki next, but it does not seem to be as updated as others.  It does offer the benefit of controlling the database, which is nice for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Great Question.

I suggest looking at https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/wiki_apps instead of asking the general populus of stackoverflow.

looks like gollum is the most popular solution.

with any rails engine you will have to customize it to your needs.